# Will a read-write race condition alter the data read and written simultaneously?

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition

For example if I have the following code:

```
SomeType obj;  

void GUIThread()  
{  
    ...  
    while (true)  
        // Read and print the content of obj  
    ...  
}  

void workerThread()  
{  
    ...  
    // Do some calculation and write the result into obj  
    ...  
}
```

For performance reasons, I can't afford to use mutex or anything alike on `obj`, and I don't need exact accuracy of what `GUIThread` prints (`obj` stores the running computation results of `workerThread`, which can be considered as a "running total". What `GUIThread` needs to do  is just to show the approximate progress of the calculation being done in `workerThread`). What I want to make sure is that the read-write race condition between `GUIThread` and `workerThread` doesn't alter the data stored in `obj`, and won't cause the program to crash. Is that true?

P.S. `SomeType` contains built-in integer types and a `std::bitset<T>`, but only the former will be accessed simultaneously. The `bitset` remains untouched by `GUIThread`.

P.P.S.  Maybe this is a little bit out of the topic...but I think I can store the running results in a cache in `workerThread`, and only update the actually protected (either by atomicity or mutex locking or whatever) every relatively long time period. To achieve this, I need to make sure that if the following code will work as intended:

```
struct SomeOtherType  
{  
    int a, b, c, d;  // And other primitive types  
}  

std::atomic<SomeOtherType> data;  // Will this work?
```

I wonder if this can protect `SomeOtherType`, and I think it can since there are only primitive types in `SomeOtherType`.

Comment: It depends what SomeType is.  What is that?

Comment: From what it seems, you definitely have to use read write locks.

Comment: Something to be exchanged as a simple progress counter between threads might be a [`std::atomic<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Comment: @JohnZwinck It is a user-defined structure which contains built-in integer types (`int`, `unsigned long long`, etc.) and a `std::bitset<T>`. I've tried to store the content of a `bitset<T>` into file in binary format with `fout.write((const char *)(&bits), sizeof (bits));` and read it back later into another `bitset<T>` with `fin.read((char *)(&bits2), sizeof (bits2));` and it works well, and the size of the `bitset<T>` varies with `T`, so I guess all data are stored inside the `bitset` without anything on heap or what.

Comment: @ArunMu But I just can't afford to do so...as long as it doesn't crash the program or alter the data.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No it is not as simple as that. It is a structure used to store computation results.

Comment: @ZizhengTai I was just referring to what you've been writing in your question: _'I just need to know the approximate progress of the calculation being done in workerThread'_. You should clarify this then.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you I've edited my question. And there is more info added at the end.

Comment: As for your edit: Make all of that integer types `std::atomic<>`s and you're off.

Comment: @ZizhengTai: Sorry, you need to have locks because you have a critical region. How many reads to writes ratio are you expecting ? If reads are going to be more, read-write  lock will be more efficient than your regular mutex.

Comment: If you don't want an rw lock, you can try a [sequential lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seqlock)

Comment: @ArunMu I've come up with an idea, could you please look at what I added to my question?

Comment: @ZizhengTai: You can do some tricks with that..but will just add the complexity. You can try Pavel's solution without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you structure looks like this

```
struct Data {
    int one;
    int two;
    std::bitset<SomeType> three;
}
```

If you don't want to use any kind of lock for it, you can try to swap a shared pointer to this structure. Check if your compiler supports it, it's a new feature.

```
std::shared_ptr<Data> dataPointer;

void GUIThread()  
{  
    ...  
    while (true)  {
       auto ptr = std::atomic_load(&dataPointer);
       // Read and print the content of *ptr
    ...  
}  

void workerThread()  
{  
    ...  
   // Do some calculation
   auto newPtr = std::make_shared<Data>();
   // make the new result visible to the gui thread
   std::atomic_store(&dataPointer, newPtr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this still has some kind of overhead.

Comment: Well, you can do it event cheaper by using a raw atomic pointer instead of shared_ptr, but then you will have to manage the memory manually somehow.

Comment: @PavelDavydov: How is this making sure that GUI thread wont be reading any partially updated data to the memory ?

Comment: @ArunMu cause it reads from the storage that is once build and never modified after that. The only shared resource here is dataPointer, but it is protected with atomic functions.

Comment: @PavelDavydov: May be you should edit the comment saying "Write the updated result to dataPointer". Current comment is not correct

Comment: @ArunMu it actually makes a new result visible to another thread, it doesn't update the previous one. Is the new comment better?

Answer (score 4):

What you are saying is "I am writing code with undefined behavior. Will it do what I want anyway?". The only answer is nobody knows except possible of the compiler writer.

It seems likely your code will do what you want because it seems the simplest way to implement the compiler. But it might well decide that nothing outside of your loop can be writing to that variable because if it did it would be a data race and therefore the standard says nothing about what it will do and then decide to replace the variable by a constant in that part of the program as it can't change and re-use that memory to store the value of another pointer in so your other thread will set a completely unconnected value to null and crash your program an hour later. It's unlikely of course but I can see how it could happen.

Undefined behavior is just that - undefined. It literally could do anything. Some things are clearly more likely than others but do you really want to risk formatting your user's disk because you thought "undefined" didn't apply to your program, no matter how small the risk appeared to be?

Comment: I have seen that very thing happen. A loop that didn't update the variable but just read it, and the compiler simply hoisted all loads out of the loop, so that it never saw any concurrent updates.

Comment: +1, Also if some code works (though it has UB) on x86_64, it doesn't make it stable and doesn't mean that it would not crash on an architecture with a weaker memory model (like arm).

Comment: +1 For pointing out that the question is essentially broken. If you need synchronization, you have to pay for it. If for whatever reason this seems too expensive, redesign your program so that it becomes cheaper. Relying on UB and hoping that it will somehow work in the end is always the worst option.

Answer (score 0):

Depending heavily on the shared data type.
What can happen in a complex data type is that during a write operation, the object becomes invalid briefly (e.g. allocates a new internal buffer).

For simple data types, such as integers, floats, etc. the code will not crash on most cases **but w/o guaranties!**. These should be declared as `volatile` to avoid the compiler caching them in a register. Forcing a memory barrier will improve your result accuracy.

If you're just checking a Boolean flag or something similar, you can get away with.

If obj is thread safe, then you're OK too.

My suggestion, when in doubt, use a low overhead lock such as spinlocks.

Comment: volatile doesn't force a memory barrier in c++ as far as I know.

Comment: _' the code will not crash'_ Believe me, I've been seen enough code badly crashing because of this misconception of `volatile`!

Comment: Actually a memory barrier is not very necessary, because as I mentioned I don't need much accuracy for what's SHOWN. I just need the accuracy of what's actually STORED. Other than that, speed first.

Comment: I've fixed my answer. Yes even an int can cause issues. Very dependent on what your code with it...

Comment: @ZizhengTai: Yes, as egur said, spinlock can be used as you just want to copy the data and print it. Spinlock wont cause a context switch and is much more light weight than mutex.

Comment: @egur I've come up with an idea, could you please look at what I added to my question?

Comment: Built in integers should be fine, but you should check their value as a precaution. Define them as `volatile`. I used such a thing as a stop condition for threads (bool). Concurrent writes to these variables must be protected.